# org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I want to create mysql string array type data field.
Hence I create model class in my spring-boot gradle project as following.

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "single_questions")
    public class SingleQuestions {
        @Id
        private Integer id;
        private String[] fieldtypevalues;
    
        public SingleQuestions() {
        }
    
        public SingleQuestions(Integer id, String category, String field, String field_type, String[] fieldtypevalues) {
            this.id = id;
            this.fieldtypevalues = fieldtypevalues;
        }
    
        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }
    
        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
    
        public String[] getFieldtypevalues() {
            return this.fieldtypevalues;
        }
    
        public void setFieldtypevalues(String[] fieldtypevalues) {
            this.fieldtypevalues = fieldtypevalues;
        }
    
    }
```

This is my Repository it extends by `JpaRepository`

```java
    public interface SingleQuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<SingleQuestions,Integer>{
        
    }
```

This is controller class

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/singleques")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    public class SingleQuestionController {
        private SingleQuestionRepository singleQuestionRepository;
    
        public SingleQuestionController(SingleQuestionRepository singleQuestionRepository) {
            this.singleQuestionRepository = singleQuestionRepository;
        }
    
        @GetMapping("/getall")
        Collection<SingleQuestions> getquestions() {
            return singleQuestionRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

But when I run `getquestions()` function in controller class, it gives following error.

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:353)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
```

Comment: Could you please show DDL of your `single_questions` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Annotate your String[] field with simply `@ElementCollection`.

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
@Column(name = "field_type_values")
private String[] fieldTypeValues;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need to allow repeated values, but if that's not the case, using java.util.Set type as the collection type, along with the @ElementCollection, worked for me.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "single_questions")
    public class SingleQuestions {
        @Id
        private Integer id;

        @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
        @Column(name = "FIELD_TYPE_VALUES")
        private List<String> fieldtypevalues;
```